# Magento setup:upgrade command is not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When I hit magento setup:upgrade. I got error following error[image]

Comment: Did you install any new module?

Comment: yes. i install module

Comment: Please write full path of php instead of php then may be it will work

Comment: Most likely something is wrong with your mysql service. Check if database config is correct, if you can connect to the server and database exists. If all seems good restart mysql.